# in mongoose when i create a model with date field default as date.now , i am getting date in UTC?

Tags: reactjs, express, frontend, mern

```
const Jobs = new mongoose.Schema({
  conditions: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  job_status: {
    type: String,
    default: "Running",
  },
  submit_time: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

This is the model i have written , i have a doubt like how to create this default time in ist or asia/kolkata timezone . Is it recommended to do the timezone thing in backend or have all the conversions in FE ?

Comment: According to the [MongoDB spec](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/bson-types/#std-label-document-bson-type-date), `Date` "represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970)." This means that it does not store any time zone information anyway. If you want, you can convert the timestamp into the `Asia/Kolkota` time zone after you read it back from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the `Date` JavaScript object, the date is in UTC standard. It is calculated with the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, UTC 0 at midnight (the epoch). Depending of the methods used and your JavaScript environment, some `Date` methods will display the date to the local timezone where your JavaScript process is running and some other methods will display it to the UTC 0 timezone.

`Date.now()` does not returns a date but a simple number. It returns the number of milliseconds in UTC 0. You can add to it the offset of your timezone if you want `Date.now() + (330 * 60000)` (IST is +5:30 so 330 minutes to convert in milliseconds), but this is not how `Date` works. `Date` **should** use the epoch date (UTC +0).

`my_date = new Date()` create an instance with the `Date` constructor function. The internal number used is still the UTC +0, but your instance is a `Date` object now. It gives you access to the `Date` object with his methods to manipulate the date. If you call `my_date.toString()` you will get the date in the local timezone of the JavaScript process environment. If you call `my_date.toJSON()` you will get the UTC +0 date.

```
var my_date   = new Date();
var now       = Date.now();

console.log(my_date); // 2023-03-16T14:55:12.849Z
console.log(my_date.getTime(), now); // 1678978512849 1678978512849
console.log(my_date.toString()); // Thu Mar 16 2023 20:25:12 GMT+0530
console.log(my_date.toJSON()); // 2023-03-16T14:55:12.849Z
```

In you case, you are trying to store a number inside a mongoose `Date` type. Most of the time, the practice is to use `new Date()` instead of `Date.now()` or to change your type from `Date` to `Number`. Then, you work with your date after retrieving it from the database to display it in the timezone you choose. You can do that in the back or in the front, your choice. You can manipulate the date with your own calculations or with a library which already do the calculations for you, most famous one is [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) (edit: [not anymore](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status) - [alternatives](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations)). Note that you are using `Date.now` as a property instead of `Date.now()` as a method. Note also that you can use [timestamps](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/timestamps.html) with mongoose if you just need a creation time and an update time. Mongoose provide them because it is very common.

```
submit_time: {
  type: Number,
  default: Date.now(),
}
```

OR

```
submit_time: {
  type: Date,
  default: new Date(),
}
```

You can get details about Date object here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment-timezone library to have the job done
here's how to use it in your schema

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const istDate = moment.tz(Date.now(), "Asia/Kolkata");
const Jobs = new mongoose.Schema({
  conditions: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  job_status: {
    type: String,
    default: "Running",
  },
  submit_time: {
    type: Date,
    default: istDate, 
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the MongoDB spec, Date “represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).” This means that it does not store any time zone information anyway1. If you want, you can convert the timestamp into the Asia/Kolkota time zone after you read it back from the database1.

You can use the moment-timezone library to convert the timestamp to the Asia/Kolkata timezone

Here’s an example:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const dateIndia = moment.tz(Date.now(), "Asia/Kolkata");
console.log(dateIndia);
```

It is recommended to do the timezone conversion in the backend